# PDF file download not working in Ipad mobile browsers (both chrome and safari) - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, pdf, ipad, download, mobile-browser

I have an Angular JS application. I am trying to download a PDF file in a new tab (which comes from backend) on mobile browsers using the below code.

**this.windowHolder.windowObjectReference = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");**

**this.windowHolder.windowObjectReference.location.href = downloadContentUrl;**

where,

windowHolder is an instance of class WindowHolder which is as below.

```
class WindowHolder {

    public intervalTimeID: number;
    public intervalCallPopup: number;
    public windowObjectReference: any;

    constructor() {
        this.intervalTimeID = 0;
        this.intervalCallPopup = 0;
        this.windowObjectReference = null;
    }

    public close() {
        if (this.windowObjectReference !== null) {
            this.windowObjectReference.close();
            this.windowObjectReference = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine in all devices and browsers except **IPAD**. Same logic works fine in iphone mobile browsers (both safari and chrome). Issue is with only IPAD browsers.

**Issue in IPAD chrome:** PDF file gets downloaded but when I try to open it says file is corrupted or damaged.

**Issue in IPAD safari:** PDF file does not get downloaded at all. Instead browser shows WebKitBlobResource error

I need to fix this code so that I will be able to download PDF even in IPAD browsers. Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, safari blocks this download action because was not originated by the user. And chrome for ios it's nothing but safari with another skin.